Xcode 16 bitcode error
After building my project with Xcode 16.1, I encounter validation errors when attempting to upload the app to the App Store. The errors specifically point to the ServiceCore and ServiceChat frameworks included in the ServiceSDK/Chat pod version ~> 246.0.1.
Error Messages:
Asset validation failed (90482)
Invalid Executable. The executable './Frameworks/ServiceCore.framework/ServiceCore' contains bitcode. (ID: de60c4b1-c996-4991-9ca8-e8317bb2afe0)
Asset validation failed (90482)
Invalid Executable. The executable './Frameworks/ServiceChat.framework/ServiceChat' contains bitcode. (ID: 955144e6-43cf-48b2-ad3b-96b94e039afa)
Steps to Reproduce:
1.  Integrate the ServiceSDK/Chat pod version ~> 246.0.1 into the project using CocoaPods.
2.  Build the project using Xcode 16.1.
3.  Attempt to validate and upload the app to the App Store.
Actual Behavior:
App Store validation fails with errors indicating that the executables in ServiceCore.framework and ServiceChat.framework contain bitcode, which is no longer supported.
Environment:
•   Xcode Version: 16.1
•   CocoaPods Version: 1.16.2
•   Target Platform: iOS
•   pod 'ServiceSDK/Chat': 246.0.1
are there any solutions?
